# can somebody explain the value of array numbers[3] and numbers[6] in following c code?

Tags: arrays, c

Sample Program Using Arrays here we need to find final output of code but I can not get the same output as the compiler gets. I am getting wrong output in numbers[3] and numbers[6].

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int numbers[10];
    int i, index = 2;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        numbers[i] = i * 10;
    numbers[8] = 25;
    numbers[5] = numbers[9] / 3;
    numbers[4] += numbers[2] / numbers[1];
    numbers[index] = 5;
    ++numbers[index];
    numbers[numbers[index++]] = 100;
    numbers[index] = numbers[numbers[index + 1] / 7]--;

    for (index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        printf("numbers[ %d ] = %d\n", index, numbers[index]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think it should be vs what it actually comes out to be?

Comment: *"i can not get the same output as the compiler gets"* - what compiler? *Your* compiler? I suspect *your* compiler is deliver precisely the code that produces the output *you're* getting. Your post should include *both* your expected output and your actual output, calling out the differences between them.

Comment: _but i can not get the same output as the compiler gets_. You mean your expected output is different from the actual output? This is the perfect task for a debugger, where you can step thru line-by-line and see where your expectations deviate from reality. Also recommend splitting up some of those complicated one-liners.

Comment: You should write a function that prints the value of `index` followed by all the elements of the array on a single line. Then you can call that function after each line of code to see what the code is doing. Of course, you could also just step through the code with a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

1. The easiest thing is to display the value of `index` and `numbers` in your debugger then execute each line till you are surprised.  If your debugger supports it, you can also run your program in reverse.
2. You could modify your program with a function that prints out `index` and `numbers` then run that function after every significant change.
3. If you want to do it manually you could reason about the program in reverse by hand.  From the output of your program:

```
numbers[ 3 ] = 100
numbers[ 6 ] = 99
```

so let's start with the last assignment:

```
numbers[ index ] = numbers[ numbers[ index + 1 ] / 7 ]-- =>
numbers[3] = numbers[numbers[4] / 7]-- =>
 = numbers[(40 + 20 / 10) / 7 ]-- =>
 = numbers[6]--
```

As `index = 3` from the post increment in `numbers[ numbers[ index++ ] ] = 100;` of the initial value of `2` set with `int i, index = 2`.  `numbers[ 4 ] += numbers[ 2 ] / numbers[ 1 ];` which just uses the initial values set in the loop `numbers[ i ] = i * 10`.

We know, from the output, that `numbers[3]` the assigned the value `100` and `numbers[6]` is decremented to `99`. The only place we assign the value 100 is the previous line `numbers[ numbers[ index++ ] ] = 100` so we just need to convince ourselves that the left hand side is `numbers[6]`:

```
numbers[ numbers[ index++ ] ]  =>
numbers[numbers[2]] =>
numbers[6]
```

As `index = 2` from the initial assignment discussed above, and `numbers[2] = 6` from `++numbers[ index ]` from the previous value of `5` set with `numbers[ index ] = 5;`.

The moral of the story is to prefer single assignment :-)

Answer (score 0):

All the magic has happened in the last two lines:

```
numbers[numbers[index++]] = 100;
numbers[index] = numbers[numbers[index + 1] / 7]--;
```

I would suggest you to use a debugger and add `numbers[3]` and `numbers[6]` to the `watcher`. And then set a breakpoint at this `numbers[numbers[index++]] = 100;` line.

##### number[6]

1. `index` was 2, so `numbers[index++]` will give `6` due to these two lines

```c
numbers[index] = 5; // numbers[2] = 5
++numbers[index]; // numbers[2] = 5 + 1 = 6
```

2. Now, `numbers[numbers[index++]] = 100;` will become `numbers[6] = 100;`
3. Now, `index++` will execute making it `3`
4. Hence, `numbers[6]` is now `100`

##### numbers[3]

1. Now decode this line:

```c
numbers[index] = numbers[numbers[index + 1] / 7]--;
```

2. `index` is now `3`, so `numbers[index + 1]` is equal to `numbers[4]` which is equal to 42 which when divided by 7 becomes `6`
3. Now, `numbers[3] = numbers[6] = 100`
4. After `numbers[3]` becomes 100, then `numbers[6]` will be decresed by 1 due to post-decrement operator `--`
5. **Hence, `numbers[3] = 100` and `numbers[6] = 99`**